# How do I restore my system back to windows 8.1 (from ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, restore

Not knowing what I was doing I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS over my windows 8.1, technically erasing everything off the hard drive and replacing it with linux. (I was trying to set up so I can dual boot windows and ubuntu, but I ended up replacing everything with ubuntu.)

How do I go back or reinstall windows on my laptop? I've got a flash/usb stick and I've got a windows .iso file. What is the simplest way to restore my system back to windows ONLY?

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I'm new to all this - with very limited knowledge, but I'm willing to learn*

Comment: Only if you get a Windows image from your vendor can you install Windows using your Product key that is embedded in the UEFI. That is for the vendor OEM version only. Some vendors will send you the image for just a nominal charge. Some have also been able to get the recovery image from an identical model from the store where purchased.

Answer (score -1):

you can burn the windows.iso in liunx. and reboot and reinstall windows that way.

so you boot in ubuntu, and launch brasero, burn the windows.iso and reboot.

another solution may be to reinstall using an OEM partition that contains all the file to reinstall windows. I don't know how. May be use boot the windows cd and look for a recover or reinstall option ?

Comment: This will run for a short period:  The embedded product key that is used with computers shipped with Windows 8 will not activate a downloaded ISO, unless that happens to be an ISO from the computer vendor

Comment: Since Ubuntu overwrote all there partitions, there is no OEM system restore partition. Downvoting.